# Does season package support splines?

Tags: r, spline

I was running a casecross function in season package with this code

```
library(season)
library(splines)

data(CVDdaily)
CVDdaily<-subset(CVDdaily,date<=as.Date('1987-12-31')) 

# Effect of ozone on CVD death

model1<- casecross(cvd ~ o3mean+tmpd+Mon+Tue+Wed+Thu+Fri+Sat, data=CVDdaily)
```

But when I use the natural splines I get an error message "Error in ns(tmpd, df = 6) : object 'tmpd' not found"

```
model2<-casecross(cvd ~ o3mean + ns(tmpd, df=6) +Mon+Tue+Wed+Thu+Fri+Sat, data=CVDdaily)
```

Does it mean that the package has no support for splines? If yes, I would appreciate any ideas on how to adjust the nonlinear effect of temperature using a season package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fit splines in season using the dlnm package. (I've used 4 degrees of freedom rather than 6).

```
library(season)
library(dlnm)
data(CVDdaily)
CVDdaily = subset(CVDdaily,date<=as.Date('1987-12-31')) 
t.spline = crossbasis(CVDdaily$tmpd,lag=0,argvar=list(fun="ns",df=4))
model2 = casecross(cvd ~ o3mean + t.spline +Mon+Tue+Wed+Thu+Fri+Sat, data=CVDdaily)
summary(model2)
```

To get a nice plot of the estimated spline you need to extract the coefficients and the variance-covariance matrix.

```
coef = coefficients(model2$c.model)[2:5]
var.cov = model2$c.model$var[2:5,2:5]
pred.t = crosspred(basis=t.spline, at=45:86, vcov=var.cov, coef=coef, model.link='identity')
plot(pred.t,"overall")
```

Comment: Thanks for this input. The code and implementation of spline works on the CVDdaily data, but spline basis does not seem to work with all data sets. I have tried on two different data and got "Error in xj[i, , drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds" error message.

Comment: That could be due to missing data. Are there any missing values in your dependent or independent variables?

Comment: I removed all missing values with df1<-df[complete.cases(df),] and still have similar error message.

Comment: Try starting with a very simple model and then add elements one by one. This will help narrow down where the problem is. It's hard to help without seeing the data or the code.

Comment: Look at the following code and data.No errorwith gam(mgcv)or glm, but with casecross. library(mgcv);library(dlnm);library(season)
df <- chicagoNMMAPS
df$spline.basis<-ns(df$temp,df=4);sbasis<-ns(df$temp,df=4)
mod1 <-gam(cvd ~ pm10+ s(time,bs='cr',k=6*15, fx=F)+ spline.basis + as.factor(dow) ,family=quasipoisson,na.action=na.omit,data=df) 
mod2 <-glm(cvd ~ pm10 + ns(time,df=6*15) + spline.basis + as.factor(dow),family=quasipoisson,na.action=na.omit,data=df) 
mod3<-casecross(cvd ~ pm10 + spline.basis, data=df)
mod4<-casecross(cvd ~ pm10 + sbasis, data=df)
mod5<-casecross(cvd ~ pm10, data=df)

Comment: The error in casecross occurs because of the missing data for pm10. The casecross function assumes that every day in the series is observed with no missing days. Although mod1 gives an answer it has just ignored the missing days. One option is to use imputation to estimate the missing pm10 days. Can you approve my first answer if you think it was useful?